# VB.NET: If I pass a String ByVal into a function but do not change the string, do I have one or two strings in memory?

Tags: vb.net, string, byref, byval

I know strings are immutable, so the minute you change a string reference's value .NET makes a brand new string on the heap.

But what if you don't *change* the value of a string reference; rather, you simply pass it into a function **`ByVal`** -- does this operation copy the string value on the heap as well?  My inclination is "no," but I'd like to confirm.

For example:

```
Public Function IsStringHello(ByVal test As String) As Boolean 
  Return (String.Compare(test, "Hello") = 0)    
End Function
```

Calling program:

```
Dim myWord as String = "Blah"
Dim matchesHello as Boolean = IsStringHello(myWord)
```

I know passing `myWord` by value makes a copy of the **reference** to "Blah", but since I have not tried to change the string itself, would it make another copy of the string on the heap?

Comment: Why do people compare strings in this odd way ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859005/string-comparison-performance/859078

Comment: Using String.Compare lets you specify case sensitivity.  This might be clearer than uppercasing strings before comparing them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By the way, string interning is completely unrelated to that. The rule for passing parameters to functions is the same for all reference types (and really, all types), no matter how they are managed internally.

The rule is simple and you have stated it correctly: pass by value copies the *reference*, not the *target*. No heap space is copied here.

Comment: interning is not directly related. You said: The rule is the same for all reference types (and really, all types), no matter how they are managed internally - I think you say it for copy of reference & not interning. right?

Answer (score 4):

No. it still uses the **copy of the reference** to the "Blah".
What makes you think, it will?

On a side note, string are interned.

```
string s = "hello";
string t = "hello";
```

s & t both refer to the same string (because it is interned). If you modify s or t, it will create a new string, then.

Comment: I had a strange (foolish?) thought maybe merely making a copy of a reference to an immutable object caused a copy of the object itself, too.  I strongly suspected that this was NOT the case, but I wanted to confirm.  Great side-note about the "interning" of strings -- I did not know that.  Thanks!

Comment: String *constants* are interned. Strings you create in other ways aren't interned.

Comment: @JonSkeet - ahhh...so in shahkalpesh's answer above where we assign two references to the same string *literal* does not mean they refer to the same string on the heap?

Comment: @Jon: if string s = "hello"; string t = "ello"; string z = "h" + t; do s & z point to same instance?

Comment: what does it mean by internedf?

Comment: @SharenEayrs: Please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.intern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. Also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

Answer (score 2):

Passing objects ByVal creates a copy of the *pointer*, not the object itself. Here's a demonstration:

```
Module Module1
    Dim original As String = "Hello world"

    Sub PassByReferenceTest(ByVal other As String)
        Console.WriteLine("object.ReferenceEquals(original, other): {0}", _
            Object.ReferenceEquals(original, other))
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        PassByReferenceTest(original)
        Console.ReadKey(True)
    End Sub
End Module
```

This program outputs the following:

```
object.ReferenceEquals(original, other): True
```

So, the original string and the string we passed by value exist at the same address in memory address. You're not making a copy of the string itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is short, no. It passes a ref to the string. Only one instance of the string itself.

Answer (score 0):

string is a reference type. If you pass it by value, what you are passing is the value of the reference.

The only way you'd get another copy on the heap would be to change the variable's value.

Answer (score 0):

A variable of type `System.String` effectively holds an "object-ID".  Suppose that `Object #1934` is a string with the characters `"Blah"`, and you say `Dim myWord As String = "Blah"`.  The compiler will then store `Object #1934` into `myWord`.  Calling `IsStringHello(myWord)` would then cause that function to be called with its `test` parameter equal to `Object #1934`.  In your example, there would be two variables of type `System.String` in memory--`myWord` and `test`, and both would hold the content `Object #1934`.